# PDO quote in my request

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY :order_by :order_dir LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset
```

My params array:

```
Array
(
    [order_by] => price
    [order_dir] => ASC
    [limit] => 50
    [offset] => 0
)
```

And I have a function for bindValues:

```
    public function query($sql, $params=array(), $limit = null, $offset = null){

            try { 

                if (!is_null($offset) && !is_null($limit)) {
                    $sql .= ' LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset';
                    $params['limit']        =  (int)$limit;
                    $params['offset']       =   (int)$offset;
                }

                $stmt = $this->database->prepare($sql); 

                foreach($params as $key => $value) {
                        if(is_int($value)) {
                            $param = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                        } elseif(is_bool($value)) {
                            $param = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                        } elseif(is_null($value)) {
                            $param = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                        } elseif(is_string($value)) {
                            $param = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                        } else {
                            $param = FALSE;
                        }

                        if($param) $stmt->bindValue(":$key", $value, $param);
                }

                $stmt->execute();
                return $stmt;

            } catch(PDOException $e){
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
   }
```

I'm trying to get products:

```
$result->products   = $db->query($sql, $arr, 50, 0)->fetchAll();
```

My raw query I think looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY "price" "ASC" LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

The query above is wrong. It should be:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `order by
   case when :order_dir='ASC' then :order_by end ASC,
   case when :order_dir='DESC' then :order_by end DESC ...`

Comment: Please clarify your comment

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` for this like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE 1=1 
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN :order_dir='ASC' THEN price END ASC,
   CASE WHEN :order_dir='DESC' THEN price END DESC
LIMIT :limit 
OFFSET :offset
```

it will become:

```
ORDER BY
   price ASC,
   NULL DESC
```

or:

```
ORDER BY
   NULL ASC,
   price DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't replace column names with PDO parameters. You have to check the values manually. This is a great [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter) answering your question.